# How to pass parameter as property name in py2neo?

Tags: csv, neo4j, cypher, py2neo

I get error while passing parameter as property name. I did not get any error while passing parameter as property value by writing {param}. But this is not working in the case of passing parameter as property name.

Here is my code.

```
query = 'Merge(c1:Customer{user_id: {user_id1},{user_id2}:{cell}})'
g.run(query, user_id1=int(row['user_id']), user_id2=str(cidx),cell=cell)
```

Here `cidx, cell, row['user_id']` are parameters.

`{user_id1}` parameter is working.

But it does not take `{user_id2}` as parameter to add property name

Comment: What error do you get? And could you please provide some code? Which code you tried is not working and which does work?

Comment: Hi John,
Thanks for replying.Here is my code.
query = 'Merge(c1:Customer{user_id: {user_id1},{user_id2}:{cell}})'
             g.run(query,user_id1=int(row['user_id']),user_id2=str(cidx),cell=cell)
Here cidx, cell, row['user_id']  are parameters.  {user_id1} parameter is working. But it does not take {user_id2} as parameter to add property name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Cypher queries cannot be parametrized by Property names.**

**Parameters can be used for:**

- literals and expressions
- node and relationship ids
- for explicit indexes only: index values and queries

**Parameters cannot be used for the following constructs, as these form part of the query structure that is compiled into a query plan:**

- property keys; so, `MATCH (n) WHERE n.$param = 'something'` is invalid
- relationship types
- labels

**Refer [Neo4j Documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/parameters/) for more details.**

**EDIT:**

You can format string to add property name as:

```
query = 'Merge(c1:Customer{user_id: {user_id1}, %s :{cell}})' % str(cidx)
```

Remove the parameter **`user_id2`** from run method:

```
g.run(query, user_id1=int(row['user_id']), cell=cell)
```

Comment: Any other alternatives?

Comment: You can format the string in python, before running. Can you share your code snippet in the question?

Comment: You can refer this question for details:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55006763/allow-parameters-for-depth-in-cypher-query/55007944#55007944

Comment: Hi Raj,Thanks for the information. Here is my code. query = 'Merge(c1:Customer{user_id: {user_id1},{user_id2}:{cell}})' g.run(query,user_id1=int(row['user_id']),user_id2=str(cidx),cell=cell) Here cidx, cell, row['user_id'] are parameters. {user_id1} parameter is working. But it does not take {user_id2} as parameter to add property name